# React native init error cannot find module-> node_modules\react-native\package.json'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So, when i try to create a new project using -> react-native init abc.
Everything goes well until it says it cannot find package json.
And then it ends up only having package json in the new abc folder.

Appreciate any help thanks.

Command Prompt Error 1
[image: Command Prompt Error 1]
Command Prompt Error 2
[image: Command Prompt Error 2]

Comment: What is your node version ?

Comment: @WilomGfx v6.10.1

Comment: I encountered this when trying to create a react app within a Yarn Workspaces mono-repo. I ended up just running it outside of the mono-repo then manually moving the generated folder into the mono-repo and that worked. There might be something wrong with my mono-repo setup, and if I could fix it, maybe I could get this to work properly, but for the time being, this hack works well enough.

Comment: metro.config.js is for some reason importing package.json, so is the other file. find then and fix the path, it will be good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reinstalling the node modules again. Go to the root directory of the project and remove the current node modules and install again.

These are the commands :
sudo rm -rf node_modules && npm install

Comment: god damn it, just needed to reinstall the node to the lasted version. the CURRENT version not the LTS version.

Comment: still no good for me

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!